# Gen­er­ate All Strings of n bits, con­sider A[0..n-1] is an array of size n

Tags: java, recursion

```
public class GenerateAllStrings {

    int []arrA;

    public GenerateAllStrings(int n)
    {
        arrA = new int[n];
    }

    public void nBits(int n)
    {
        if(n <= 0)
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arrA));
        else
        {
            arrA[n-1] = 0;
            nBits(n-1);
            arrA[n-1] = 1;
            nBits(n-1);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        int n = 3;
        GenerateAllStrings i = new GenerateAllStrings(n);
        i.nBits(n);
    }


}
```

I am unable to understand recursion in this program. why is n set to 1 after printing the first set of value( I thought it should be zero)? Please explain.

Comment: A question which just has the code ? Explain your problem sir!

Comment: Each of the position can have any of the two values `0` or `1` so here first time we set `nth` bit to `0` and do recursion for `n-1` bits and then we make `nth` bit `1` and recursion for `n-1` bits. This way it generates all possible strings by setting each positions value by 0 or 1.

Answer (score 0):

The values you are passing are (n-1). So when it prints the first set of values, the value of n in the function is 0 but when it comes out of that recursion it is 1 since you passed the argument as (n-1) which is 0. Thus coming out of the function it gets the original value of n which was 1.

Answer (score 0):

This program is first setting element at `(n-1)th` index to `0` and then calling `next level recursion` to `print` this setted value and after doing this, it again sets the `(n-1)th` index element to `1` and then calling next level recursion to print this setted value.

This sort of logic is happening at each level.

In order to print all the strings consists of `0` and `1`, this program is just first setting the (n-1)th value to 0( Here in the base case it's value will be printed 0) and then calling the recursion on (n-1)th value in order to print this setted value.
Therefore `nBits(n)` is setting `(n-1)th` value to `0`, `nBits(n-1)` is setting the `(n-2)th` value to `0` and so on.So in the base case, `0` will be printed everywhere.

After printing the value `0000...` in the base case, array element at `0th` index is set to `1` in `nBits(1)` and then it's just printed by calling `nBits(0)` which prints `1000...`