# Can't understand this backtracking question from book

Tags: python, algorithm, recursive-backtracking

Currently I am studying Data Structure and Algorithmic thinking with python by Narasimha Karumanchi.
But I can't understand one question which is as follows:

Q. Generate all the binary strings with n-bits. Assume A[0..n-1] is an array of size n.

Sol:

```py
def appendAtFront(x,L):
    return [x+element for element in L]
def bitStrings(n):
    if n == 0: return []
    if n == 1: return ["0", "1"]
    else:
        return (appendAtFront("0", bitStrings(n-1) + appendAtFront("1", bitStrings(n-1))))

print(bitStrings(4))
```

OUTPUT:

```
['0000', '0001', '00010', '00011', '00100', '00101', '001010', '001011', '01000', '01001', '010010', '010011', '010100', '010101', '0101010', '0101011']
```

Can any one explain me what this question is asking?

Comment: Are you sure that is the exact solution? It seems to have a parenthesis wrong in the recursive return. The result includes strings of > 4 characters, so something doesn't look right.

Comment: @slothrop Yes this is exact solution and I copied output directly from jupyter notebook.

Comment: OK, it's incorrect :)

Comment: It should be `return (appendAtFront("0", bitStrings(n-1)) + appendAtFront("1", bitStrings(n-1)))` - pay close attention to the parentheses.

Comment: Not clear what is wanted, nor why backtracking is mentionned. But a shorter solution is `def bitStrings(n):
    if n==0: return [""]
    return [p+s for p in ["0","1"] for s in bitStrings(n-1)]`

Answer (score 2):

You have misquoted the code from the book *"Data Structure and Algorithmic thinking with python"* by Narasimha Karumanchi. The output you have included clearly shows the result is wrong: the strings have differing lengths, and none of the strings have three consecutive "1" characters.

Here is a screenshot of pages 45 and 46:

> [image]

As you can see, you have placed the parentheses differently in the `return` statement. Other insignificant difference are in the name of the first function, and the `print` statement, which uses Python 2 syntax. The code in the book is like this:

```py
def appendAtBeginningFront(x, L):
    return [x + element for element in L]
    
def bitStrings(n):
    if n == 0: return []
    if n == 1: return ["0", "1"]
    else:
        return (appendAtBeginningFront("0", bitStrings(n-1)) + appendAtBeginningFront("1", bitStrings(n-1)))

print bitStrings(4)
```

It produces the correct output.

### The issues in the book...

The text below the code says:

> Let () be the running time of `Binary(n)`. Assume function `printf` takes time O(1).
>
> [image]
>
> Using Subtraction and Conquer Master theorem we get: () = O(2). This means the algorithm for generating bit-strings is optimal.

This is problematic:

1. The presented Python code has no `Binary` function, nor a `printf` function. This clearly refers to some other C code that is not presented.
2. The time complexity of the presented code is not O(2), but O(²2).

The explanation for these errors is that this book was a later variant of the book *"Data Structures and Algorithms Made Easy"* by the same author, but that book used C code which got replaced with Python code in the book you are looking at.

### The book "Data Structures and Algorithms Made Easy"

In the *earlier* book, we find at the same spot the following:

> ### 2.12 Backtracking: Problems & Solutions
>
> **Problem 3**   Generate all the strings of  bits. Assume [0..−1] is an array of size .
>
> **Solution:**
>
> ```c
> void Binary(int n) {
>     if (n < 1)
>         printf("%s", A);      // Assume array A is a global variable
>     else {
>         A[n-1] = 0;
>         Binary(n - 1);
>         A[n-1] = 1;
>         Binary(n - 1);
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> Let () be the running time of `Binary(n)`. Assume function `printf` takes time O(1).
>
> [image]
>
> Using Subtraction and Conquer Master theorem we get: () = O(2). This means the algorithm for generating bit-strings is optimal.

Now the text below the code makes sense, but this C code is drastically different from the Python code in the book you refer to:

- It does not produce a collection (array, list) of strings, but prints strings.
- It doesn't produce new strings for each combination, but mutates the same string. (Contrary to Python strings, C-strings are mutable)

By consequence, the time complexity is *different* for these different implementations.

So the author (or their editor) was sloppy in replacing the C code with Python code, without apparently realising the text below that code snippet is no longer true.

### What is the true complexity?

Honestly, assuming O(1) complexity for the C `printf` function is not fair: printing  characters has a time complexity of O(). Although the text in the C version is consistent, if we decide to *print* the results, then we have to agree there are 2 characters in the output, and so the time complexity cannot be just O(2).

On the other hand, the Python code is inefficient, as it performs unnecessary extra work by copying a string each time a character needs to be prefixed. This means for one string in the output, the code has already generated strings of length 1, of length 2, ... up to the string's final length. That represents a time complexity of 1+2+3+...+ = O(²) for one string, and thus the total time complexity becomes O(²2). This extra factor of  can be avoided.

If we wanted to translate the C implementation to Python, we'd have to represent strings as lists of characters, so that we *can* mutate these "strings". Here is how that would look if we stay as close as possible to the C code:

```py
n = 4
A = [0] * n

def binary(n: int):
    if n < 1:
        print(A)
    else:
        A[n-1] = 0
        binary(n - 1)
        A[n-1] = 1
        binary(n - 1)

binary(n)
```

This is not very elegant Python code, as we should not mix printing with logic, and should not avoid global variables. So to improve on that, and produce *strings*, we could write:

```py
def binary(n: int):
    lst = ["0"] * n

    def recur(n: int):
        if n < 0:
            yield "".join(lst)
        else:
            lst[n] = "0"
            yield from recur(n - 1)
            lst[n] = "1"
            yield from recur(n - 1)

    return list(recur(n - 1))

print(binary(4))
```

This has a time complexity of O(2), just like the C code if we don't ignore the printing cost in that code.

Answer (score 1):

The question is asking you to generate all possible binary strings of length n. In binary, each digit can be either 0 or 1, so for a binary string of length n, you can have 2^n possible combinations.

e.g.:

```
n = 1 --> [0, 1]
n = 2 --> [00, 01, 10, 11]
n = 3 --> [000, 001, 010, 011, 100, 101, 110, 111]
```

Comment: What do you make of the *"Assume A[0..n-1] is an array of size n"* part of the question?

Comment: No idea, it doesn't feature in the provided solution, and it doesn't really make sense to me why one would need an `A[0..n-1]` array.

Comment: I searched a bit, and it looks like there are some approaches where you build an array of length `n`, keep mutating it, and take copies to get the distinct strings. For example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44713188/generate-all-strings-of-n-bits-consider-a0-n-1-is-an-array-of-size-n. I guess that's what the textbook is getting at, but it doesn't seem like the most natural way to solve the problem.

Comment: It might make sense to mutate an array in a context where you want to claim that your algorithm only uses O(n) space (as opposed to 2**n which is required to output a full list of all possible bitstrings), and leave the responsibility of making the copies on the caller. For instance in python you could use keyword `yield` to repeatedly yield the same mutable array after mutating it; this way your function would only use O(n) space. This can make sense if the caller then uses the bitstrings to do some computations "online", without keeping them all in memory simultaneously.